# PyCharm on remote server doesn't show unused imports, #fixme and etc

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, remote-server

In the local project, PyCharm functions work correctly [Local functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlGID.png)

```
import pandas as pd #unused import notification
# FIXME #highlight
# TODO #highlight
```

However, on the remote server, they seem to be broken [Remote functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF1y2.png)

```
import pandas as pd #no unused import notification
# FIXME #no highlight
# TODO #no highlight
```

I tried to change things in the interpreter and even added a remote interpreter, but this doesn't fix my problem

What is the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you mean by "_they seem to be broken_"?

Comment: I mean, that PyCharm shows neither an unused import notification nor highlights todo or fixme.